# If $a^4+b^4+c^4=3$ so $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{1}{3-2ab}\leq3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math

> Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be non-negative numbers such that $a^4+b^4+c^4=3$. Prove that:
> $$\frac{1}{3-2ab}+\frac{1}{3-2ac}+\frac{1}{3-2bc}\leq3$$

I tried SOS, C-S and more, but without success.

By brute force methods with computer we can get that this inequality is true, but I am looking for an human proof, which we can release during a competition.

Thank you!

Comment: Oh, I see the problem now.

Comment: @Sangchul Lee Thank you for your interest!

Comment: I have a partial proof of this do you want to see that ? Moreover it's short and clear .Perhaps this could inspire you... :)

Comment: @FatsWallers I think it's better to give a full proof.

Comment: Before I post my proof are you agree with this fact : the maximum of $ab$ with the two conditions $a^4+b^4+c^4=3$ and $a\geq b \geq c $ is $$\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}$$ ?

Comment: @FatsWallers Yes, of course! It follows from AM-GM.

Answer (score 1):

First of all we prove this inequality with $a^4+b^4+c^4=3$:

$$\frac{2}{3-a(b+c)}+\frac{1}{3-2bc}\leq 3$$

If we put this with $a\geq b \geq c$ :

$a=A$

$b=AB$

$c=AC$

Your inequality is equivalent to this :

$$\frac{2\sqrt{1+B^4+C^4}}{\sqrt{3}(\sqrt{3}\sqrt{1+B^4+C^4}-B-C)}+\frac{\sqrt{1+B^4+C^4}}{\sqrt{3}(\sqrt{3}\sqrt{1+B^4+C^4}-2BC)}$$

Or:

$$\frac{2(B+C)}{\sqrt{3}(\sqrt{3}\sqrt{1+B^4+C^4}-B-C)}+\frac{BC}{\sqrt{3}(\sqrt{3}\sqrt{1+B^4+C^4}-2BC)}+1$$

Now the idea is to use an identity :

$B^4+C^4=((B+C)^2-2BC)^2-2B^2C^2$

The inequality becomes :

$\frac{2(B+C)}{3(\sqrt{3}\sqrt{1+((B+C)^2-2BC)^2-2B^2C^2}-B-C)}+\frac{BC}{3(\sqrt{3}\sqrt{1+((B+C)^2-2BC)^2-2B^2C^2}-2BC)}+1$

Notice that we have just in the inequality elements of the form $BC$ or $B+C$

So we put :

$B+C=\lambda=constant$

And now remark that $bc$ have his maximum when $B=\frac{\lambda}{2}$ and $C=\frac{\lambda}{2}$

It's the same thing in the general inequality (we can replace $BC$ by $BC=\frac{\lambda^2}{4}$) so we have this inequality with one variable :

$$\frac{2(\lambda)}{3(\sqrt{3}\sqrt{1+((\lambda)^2-2\frac{\lambda^2}{4})^2-2(\frac{\lambda^2}{4})^2}-(\lambda))}+\frac{\frac{\lambda^2}{4}}{3(\sqrt{3}\sqrt{1+((\lambda)^2-2\frac{\lambda^2}{4})^2-2(\frac{\lambda^2}{4})^2}-2\frac{\lambda^2}{4})}+1$$

Wich is equivalent to :

$$f(\lambda)=\frac{2(\lambda)}{3(\sqrt{3}\sqrt{1+\frac{\lambda^4}{8})}-(\lambda))}+\frac{\frac{\lambda^2}{4}}{3(\sqrt{3}\sqrt{1+\frac{\lambda^4}{8}}-2\frac{\lambda^2}{4})}+1$$

Now it's easy to remark that the function have a maximum for $\lambda=2$ wich is $3$

So we have prove the following inequality with some conditions :

$$\frac{2}{3-a(b+c)}+\frac{1}{3-2bc}\leq 3$$

Now the idea is to combine this with the theorem of logarithmic majorization for three variables :

Theorem :

Let $a,b,c,d,e,f$ be positive real number , with $a\geq b \geq c$ , $e\geq d \geq f $ under the three following conditions :

$a\geq d$ , $ab\geq de$ , $abc\geq def$ so we have :

$$a+b+c\geq d+e+f$$

The inequality to prove is :

$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{2-3ab}\leq \frac{2}{3-e(f+d)}+\frac{1}{2-3df}\leq 3 $$

With $a^4+b^4+c^4=e^4+f^4+d^4=3$

And $d=1$,$f=bc$,$e=(2-(bc)^4)^{\frac{1}{4}}$

Now its easy to see that we have :

$\frac{1}{2-3ab}\geq \frac{1}{2-3ac}\geq \frac{1}{2-3bc}$

And

$\frac{1}{3-e(f+d)}\geq \frac{1}{2-3df}$

But as we have said in a comment the maximum of $ab$ is $\sqrt{1.5}$
and $0\leq bc
 \leq 1$

And :

$e(f+d)=(2-(bc)^4)^{\frac{1}{4}}(1+bc)\geq \sqrt{1.5}$ for $bc\geq0.5$

So we have :

$\frac{1}{3-e(f+d)}\geq \frac{1}{2-3\sqrt{1.5}}\geq\frac{1}{2-3ab}\geq \frac{1}{2-3ac}$

So you just have to apply the theorem to have :

$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{2-3ab}\leq \frac{2}{3-e(f+d)}+\frac{1}{2-3df}\leq 3 $$

For the case $bc\leq 0.5$ you just have to change the parameters like this :

$d=\frac{1}{2}$,$f=2bc$,$e=(2-\frac{1}{16}-(16bc)^4)^{\frac{1}{4}}$

So we have :

$e(f+d)=(2-\frac{1}{16}-(16bc)^4)^{\frac{1}{4}}(1+bc)\geq \sqrt{1.5}$ for $bc\leq0.5$

And the reasoning is the same.

Done!

Comment: Now it would right... :)

Answer (score 1):

Using AM-GM, we have
$\frac{1}{3-2ab} = \frac{3+ 2ab}{9-4a^2b^2} \le \frac{3+a^2+b^2}{9-4a^2b^2}$. It suffices to prove that
$$\frac{3+a^2+b^2}{9-4a^2b^2}
+ \frac{3+b^2+c^2}{9-4b^2c^2} + \frac{3+c^2+a^2}{9-4c^2a^2} \le 3.$$

Letting $x = a^2, y = b^2, z = c^2$, we have $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 3$. We need to prove that
$$\frac{3+x+y}{9-4xy} + \frac{3+y+z}{9-4yz} + \frac{3+z+x}{9-4zx} \le 3. \tag{1}$$

We use pqr method.

Let $p = x + y + z, q = xy + yz + zx, r = xyz$.

The condition $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 3$
becomes $p^2 - 2q = 3$.
Thus, $q = \frac{p^2 - 3}{2}$.
Since $q \ge 0$, we have $p\ge\sqrt 3$.
Using $p^2 \ge 3q$, we have $p \le 3$.
Thus, $\sqrt 3 \le p \le 3$.

(1) becomes
$$-192r^2 + (384p - 32q + 108)r + 36pq - 162p - 756q + 1458 \ge 0$$
or
\begin{align*}
 &-\frac{1}{48}\, \left( 96\,p-8\,q+27-96\,r \right) ^{2} \\
 &\qquad +4\,pq-54\,p-765\,q+{
  \frac {23571}{16}}+192\,{p}^{2}+\frac43\,{q}^{2}
 \ge 0. \tag{2}
\end{align*}

Using $q^2 \ge 3pr$ and $q=(p^2-3)/2$ and $\sqrt 3 \le p \le 3$, we have
\begin{align*}
 &96\,p-8\,q+27-96\,r \\
 \ge\,& 96\,p-8\,q+27-96\cdot \frac{q^2}{3p}\\ 
 =\,&
 \frac{-8p^4-4p^3+144p^2+39p-72}{p}\\
 >\,& 0. \tag{3}
\end{align*}

Degree four Schur inequality yields
$$r \ge \frac{5p^2 q - p^4 - 4q^2}{6p}. \tag{4}$$

Using (2) and (3) and (4), it suffices to prove that
\begin{align*}
 &-\frac{1}{48}\, \left( 96\,p-8\,q+27-96\cdot \frac{5p^2 q - p^4 - 4q^2}{6p} \right) ^{2} \\
 &\qquad +4\,pq-54\,p-765\,q+{
  \frac {23571}{16}}+192\,{p}^{2}+\frac43\,{q}^{2}
 \ge 0
\end{align*}
or
$$\frac{(3-p)(4p^7+16p^6-72p^5-321p^4+351p^3+1746p^2-378p-432)}{3p^2} \ge 0$$
which is true.

We are done.

Answer (score 0):

*My second proof*:

**Fact 1**: It holds that, for all $x \in [0, \sqrt{3/2}]$,
$$\frac{1}{3 - 2x} \le \frac14x^4 + \frac{9}{16 - 4x^4}.$$
(*Note*: $\frac14x^4 + \frac{9}{16 - 4x^4}
- \frac{1}{3 - 2x} = \frac{(2x^7 + x^6 - x^4 - 10x^3 - 3x^2 + 4x + 11)(x - 1)^2}{(16 - 4x^4)(3 - 2x)}\ge 0$.)

By Fact 1, using $ab, bc, ca \le \sqrt{3/2}$, it suffices to prove that
$$\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \left(\frac14 (ab)^4 + \frac{9}{16 - 4(ab)^4} \right)\le 3.$$

Letting $x = a^4, y = b^4, z = c^4$, it suffices to prove that, for all $x, y, z \ge 0$ with $x + y + z = 3$,
$$\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \left(\frac14 xy + \frac{9}{16 - 4xy}\right) \le 3. \tag{1}$$

We use isolated fudging.

**Fact 2**: It holds that, for all $x, y \ge 0$ with $x + y \le 3$,
\begin{align*}
&\frac14 xy + \frac{9}{16 - 4xy}\\[6pt]
\le{}& \frac{9}{16} + \frac{7}{32}(x + y) - \frac{9}{32}(x + y)^2 + \frac{3}{32}(x + y)^3 + \frac{3}{32}xy(6 - x - y).
\end{align*}
(The proof is given at the end.)

Using Fact 2, we have
\begin{align*}
 &\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \left(\frac14 xy + \frac{9}{16 - 4xy}\right)\\[6pt]
 \le{}& \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \left(\frac{9}{16} + \frac{7}{32}(x + y) - \frac{9}{32}(x + y)^2 + \frac{3}{32}(x + y)^3 + \frac{3}{32}xy(6 - x - y)\right)\\[6pt]
 ={}& 3 + \frac{1}{16}(x + y + z - 3)(3x^2 + 3y^2 + 3z^2 + 7)\\
 ={}& 3.
\end{align*}

We are done.

---

*Proof of Fact 2*:

Let $p = x + y, q = xy$. Then $p^2 \ge 4q$.

The inequality is written as
$$\frac14 q + \frac{9}{16 - 4q}
\le \frac{9}{16} + \frac{7}{32}p - \frac{9}{32}p^2 + \frac{3}{32}p^3 + \frac{3}{32}q(6 - p)$$
or
$$f(q) := \frac{9}{16} + \frac{7}{32}p - \frac{9}{32}p^2 + \frac{3}{32}p^3 + \frac{1}{32}q(10 - 3p) - \frac{9}{16-4q} \ge 0.$$

We have $f''(q) = - \frac{288}{(16-4q)^3} < 0$. Thus, $f(q)$ is concave on $[0, 3]$.
Also, we have $f(0) = \frac{1}{32}p(3p^2 - 9p + 7) \ge 0$
and $f(p^2/4) = \frac{p(112 - 10p - 9p^2)(p - 2)^2}{128(16-p^2)} \ge 0$ for all $p\in [0, 3]$.
Thus, we have $f(q) \ge 0$ on $[0, p^2/4]$.

We are done.